# Why does venv break after rsync?

Tags: python, python-3.x, continuous-integration, rsync, python-venv

I am trying to build a CI/CD process for my Python scripts and applications. I am able to build my venv within the testing container but when I rsync it over to the target server, the version of Python seems to break. This is what I am trying:

```
- cp -a ./. $APP_DIR
- cd $APP_DIR
- python3 -m venv venv
- source venv/bin/activate
- pip3 install -r requirements.txt
...
- rsync...
```

All environments involved are running Python 3.6.8

When I activate the venv on the target server and run `which python3` I get `/usr/bin/python3` which is incorrect.

**Why? Why does venv break when deployed to a server via rsync?**

I'm new to Python development and the virtual environment process. Should venv's only be created on the server (or container) that they need to run on? Sometimes my target servers don't have python3-venv installed on them. Is it possible to deploy a venv with the code and use it to run my scripts?

Comment: You'd have to use virtualenv, but it's not 100% guaranteed to work. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/?highlight=relocatable#making-environments-relocatable This is why things like docker are preferred, since the image contains the installed packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an environment via `venv`, it stores the *absolute* path of the environment path into `bin/activate`. Additionally some symlinks are created in the new environment pointing to existing python installation.

As a consequence of this the environment is only valid on the hosts *and* path `venv` was executed. This is also stated in the documentation (some parts omitted):

> Running this command creates the target directory [...]  and places a pyvenv.cfg file in it with a home key pointing to the Python **installation from which the command was run**. It also creates a bin [...] subdirectory containing a copy/symlink of the Python binary/binaries (**as appropriate for the platform or arguments used at environment creation time**).

You can easily check this fact by these commands:

```
mkdir /tmp/example_dir_for_stackoverflow
cd /tmp/example_dir_for_stackoverflow
python3 -m venv venv
grep stackoverflow venv/bin/activate
```

It will output:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/tmp/example_dir_for_stackoverflow/venv"
```

If you rsync this environment to another system onto a different path and/or different python installation, the settings in `bin/activate` don't match and it don't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought I had duplicated the directory structure identically but maybe the problem is that it is a different Python installation. The Python versions are the same, 3.6.8, but maybe the problem is those symlinks that you mentioned. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion yout best bet is to exclude `venv` folder from rsync with

```sh
rsync --exclude 'venv'  source/ destination/
```

The `requirements.txt` file is your best friend for keeping your dependencies satisfied everywhere.

I also suggest you to install `python3-venv` package from your Linux distribution if you're satisfied by the provided Python version. Else install another Python version at all (you'll find in the Internet how to install a different Python for your distribution).

By example:

**Host 1** (This is where you develop and you may add something to your venv)

```sh
cd /tmp/
mkdir app_base # base folder for venv/ and app_code/
cd app_base/
mkdir app_code # base folder for code only

# LOCAL virtual environment creation and activatin
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

# Just an example of whatever you may need
pip install numpy
# Let's say that it could be enough for your app to work.

# Create requirements.txt
pip3 freeze >requirements.txt
```

**Server, Container, whatever remote..**

SETUP
This should run once (or at least **before** rsync). It's the same first 5 lines from the above snippet.

```sh
cd /tmp/
mkdir app_base
cd app_base/
mkdir app_code
python3 -m venv venv
```

Now that you've done the setup on the remote host, let's return to Host 1, where you develop.
You need to rsync your `app_code` and `requirements.txt` (and maybe some other stuff), but not the `venv` folder

**Host 1**

You can wrap this in a cron job

```sh
rsync -xav -e ssh --exclude 'venv' /tmp/app_base/ user@X.X.X.X:/tmp/app_base/
```

Then, finally, you can keep your server virtual environment up to your needs, directly running this on the server.

**Server, Container, whatever remote..**

```sh
cd /tmp/app_base
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Now, on the remote host, you should be able to run (the unit test of) your code.

The 'strict' answer to your bolded question

> Why? Why does venv break when deployed to a server via rsync?

is: some Python packages (like the numpy I've used in the example) provide binary routines, for performance reasons. Copying the virtual environment folder will only work in the very same Linux distribution or Windows version, with the very same architecture and Python version. And it's not the purpose virtual environments were created for.